# Sass: $color-darken with HSL color codes

Tags: css, colors, sass

I know how to use built-in functions for determining a darker color from a hex code. But how to do this with hsl? I have three colors, one primary, one darker and a lighter one. I need to write a function to calculate the difference between them and get a lighter and darker shade for them. So when I add another color code, it'll give me same percentage for lighter and darker shade.

As I understand from Sass documentation, I first need a function to get hue, saturation, and lightness of my base color, right? But what then?

These are my colors in hex:

```
$base: #7760BF;
$base-darker: #483584;
$base-lighter: #b5a9dc;
```

And here they are in hsl, just in case:

```
$base: hsl(255, 43%, 56%);
$base-darker: hsl(254, 43%, 36%);
$base-lighter: hsl(254, 42%, 76%);
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Here is one using jquery https://codepen.io/pankajparashar/pen/oFzIg

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I'm wondering about Sass solutions.

Comment: @Brad Sass is a preprocessor. So in this case, and for most Sass questions, a runtime package is not needed, and should even be avoided.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Sass, types are converted automatically. Color functions from the Sass [standard library](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html) will accept any color, rgb or hsl.

At first to generate darker and lighter colors, you can use `darken` and `lighten`. I made an example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXwGWx).

[image]

Then to know the lightness difference between colors to generate new colors with the same difference, you can use `lightness`.

```
@function get-lightness-diff($base, $color) {
    @return lightness($base) - lightness($color);
}

@function get-variant($color, $diff) {
    @if ($diff < 0) {
        @return darken($color, -$diff);
    } @else {
        @return lighten($color, $diff);
    }
}

@function get-variants($color, $diff) {
    $ret: ();
    $ret: map-merge($ret, ( darker: get-variant($color, -$diff) ));
    $ret: map-merge($ret, ( lighter: get-variant($color, $diff) ));
    @return $ret;
}

@function get-variants-from-set($color, $darker, $base, $lighter) {
    $darker-diff: get-lightness-diff($base, $darker);
    $lighter-diff: get-lightness-diff($base, $lighter);

    $ret: ();
    $ret: map-merge($ret, ( darker: get-variant($color, $darker-diff) ));
    $ret: map-merge($ret, ( lighter: get-variant($color, $lighter-diff) ));
    @return $ret;
}

$base: hsl(255, 43%, 56%);
$base-lighter: hsl(255, 43%, 66%);
$base-darker: hsl(255, 43%, 46%);

// Get a lightness diff, from the light color for example
$diff: get-lightness-diff($base, $base-lighter);

// Variants: contains a map with 'darker' and 'lighter' colors.
$variants: get-variants($base, $diff);
// Or create your lighter/darker variants manually:
$darker: get-variant($base, -10%);
$lighter: get-variant($base, 10%);

// Or all-in-one: create your variants from an other set of colors:
$other-base: hsl(255, 33%, 33%);
$other-variants: get-variants-from-set($other-base, $base-darker, $base, $base-lighter);
```

I made an other example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJrwZK), but you may have to adapt it to make it fit your needs.

[image: Variants]

---

**Edit** (11/07/17): Since I written this post, I improved the utilities we can use to generate colors variants. You can see an example at: https://codepen.io/ncoden/pen/yXQqpz?editors=1100.

Comment: Thank you for replying, ncoden. Could you, if you don't mind, explain the second get-color-variants function? I don't understand what is going on there, exactly?

Comment: And as I understood, I have to calculate the hsl difference between colors by hand and then apply this, right? Sorry I'm bombarding you with questions, I just don't get it.

Comment: I edited my reply and the Codepen to make it clearer and easier to use. **1.** `get-variants` returns a map with the `darker` and `lighter` colors, from the base color and lightness difference you provided. **2.** `get-variants-from-set` returns the same map but from a set of color (darker, base and lighter) and calculate the diff by ifself. **3.** `modify-variants` returns the same map but from an other map of variants, allowing you to generate and modify a lof of variants easily. Look at the Codepen :)

Comment: @hemoglobin Did you managed to understand and reuse my piece of code ?

Comment: Hello @hemoglobin. Don't forget to mark your question as resolved if you think I helped you enough. Your bounty will end in 4 days.

Comment: Hey @ncoden, I apologize for my uber late reply. But I had internet issues and couldn't get them fixed earlier. I think I managed to understand what you tried to do, but the thing is, it's still not giving me the result I need. The colors seem off. For example: http://pokit.org/get/img/b303a3c3b8a21ed35286fbba3136e88d.jpg

Comment: Am I using it correctly: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZymXjp?editors=1100

Comment: That looks impressive, seriously. But I don't know how to use it. Can't even read the functions. How can I determine the difference between for example this primary: #2980B9 and this primary-dark: #154360 and primary-light: #5499C7 with your code? Where exactly does that calculation happen?

Comment: - To get the difference: `get-lightness-diff($base, $color);`

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that `$ret: map-merge($ret, ( INDEX: VALUE) );` is like doing `$ret: map-set($ret, INDEX, VALUE);` but there is no native `map-set` in Sass. Also, I updated the codepen to make it simpler.

Comment: And vars $base and $color, at what do they refer to? Where do I specify them? What confuses me (and I apologize if I'm being annoying) is how did you determine the difference between the base and the lighter colors if you didn't include the lighter difference/numbers anywhere? I mean, I tried doing this with adjust-color function where I first converted hex to hsl manually (in a converter) and then just subtracted the difference with adjust-color function. It doesn't give me 100% accurate result, it's why I'm looking for other options. But that's my level of Sass, it's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148924/discussion-between-ncoden-and-hemoglobin).